# how to show user's username when logged into a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to have the header of my site reading "Logged in as " when a user is logged into my wordpress site.

I dont know how to echo the username of the current user, heres the code I'm got...

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<ul id="mem" class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Logged in as Username</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>';
} else {
echo '<ul id="mem" class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>';
}
?>
```

and I'd like to replace Username.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 8):

you can use [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) function to grab any logged in users info..

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

in your case it could be

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo '<ul id="mem" class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Logged in as '.$current_user->display_name.'</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>';
} else {
echo '<ul id="mem" class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>';
}
?>
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the code.I am trying to do the same for all woocommerce logged in users.While using your code the links arent "active" so when i press logout it doesnt log out.What do you think i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
```