# Woo commerce My account name modification?

Tags: php, woocommerce

is there any way to modify the MY Account name to be shown as the login user name on the menu?

i am able to make it show the user name on the dashboard but unable to make it show on the header menu of woo commerce [here is the part where i want to display the user name instead of my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wibwf.jpg)

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Look for the place in your theme's files for the where the account text is placed. Change it to

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo $current_user->display_name;
} 
else {
  echo 'Login to your account';
}
```

Also see [how to show user's username when logged into a wordpress site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021620/how-to-show-users-username-when-logged-into-a-wordpress-site#6022220)

Comment: tried..it still doesnt change the username on the menu